# how to convert from millisecond to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#

```
private static DateTime FromMS(long microSec)
{           
    long milliSec = (long)(microSec / 1000);
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliSec);
    DateTime v = new DateTime(time.Ticks);

    DateTime result = new DateTime(startTime.Year + v.Year, startTime.Month +            v.Month, startTime.Day + v.Day, startTime.Hour + v.Hour, startTime.Minute + v.Minute, startTime.Millisecond + v.Millisecond);

    return result;
}
```

This result is wrong... 
Why ???

Comment: What result do you get, and what result where you expecting?

Comment: You took your milliseconds, divided them by 1000 to get seconds but then loaded them as milliseconds.. ? surely you wanted to load them as they were? Surely you just wanted return new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(milliSec)

Comment: Also, I believe the 6th argument to that particular DateTime constructor overload is in seconds, not milliseconds as you have in the example code.

Answer (score 8):

You already have the result of the conversion to milliseconds when you do:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliSec);
DateTime v = new DateTime(time.Ticks); //This is the result
```

If you want to add the milliseconds to UNIX time, then all you have to do is:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliSec);
DateTime result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
result = result.Add(time);
```

If the time isn't in UTC then omit the DateTimeKind.Utc part, but it's generally a good idea to keep the time in UTC and only convert to local time when needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static DateTime FromMS(long microSec)
{
    long milliSec = (long)(microSec / 1000);
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliSec);
    return startTime.Add(time);
}
```

Comment: You still lose precision when you introduce the variable `milliSec`. If that's a problem (i.e. if you need to retain full precision), use something like `long ticks = (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 1000000) * microSec;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to convert from a Unix Epoch (with milliseconds) to a DateTime object

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpochStart = 
               DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), DateTimeKind.Utc);


public static DateTime ToDateTimeFromEpoch(this long epochTime)
{
   DateTime result = UnixEpochStart.AddMilliseconds(epochTime);
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long ticks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ticks);
dt.AddMilliseconds(milliSec);
```

Comment: should be dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(milliSec);

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1509359657633);
DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddTicks(time.Ticks);
```

This will convert milliseconds into a correct DateTime.

**NOTE:-** If you get the milliseconds from JS like `Date.now()` the millisecond you received here is for UTC. So when you convert to C# DateTime, you will get DateTime in UTC time